# How to handle different file types in Node.js

Tags: node.js, file, sharepoint, readfile, writefile

I'm trying to upload and download files to SharePoint server using [sp-request](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request) library for Node.js and SHAREPOINT REST API
I am able to handle text files but when it comes to other types of files (images, docx ...) they always end up corrupted.
So I'm wondering, if I should be using other methods to read and write files in my Node.js code.
Upload method :

```
fs.readFile('file1.png', 'utf8', function (err, file) {
spr.requestDigest('http://vm2008sharepo/')
    .then(function (digest) {
                return spr.post('http://vm2008sharepo/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(\'Documents\')/Files/Add(url=\'file1.png\')', {
                    body: file,
                    headers: {
                        'X-RequestDigest': digest,
                        'X-HTTP-Method': 'POST',
                        'IF-MATCH': '*',

                    }
                })
                    .then(postResult => {
                        console.log("File Added");
                    });


    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    });
});
```

Download method :

```
 var file = fs.createWriteStream("file2.odt");
        var path = 'file2.odt';
        spr.requestDigest('http://vm2008sharepo/')
            .then(function (digest) {
                spr.get('http://vm2008sharepo/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(\'/Documents/file2.odt\')/$value')
                    .then(function (response) {
                        try {
                            fs.writeFile(path, response.body);
                            console.log("File Downloaded");
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error.stack);
                        }
                    });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my **HTTP** calls were sending the files in **JSON** format and I just had to prevent that by adding a line to my code :

```
return spr.post('http://vm2008sharepo/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(\'Documents\')/Files/Add(url=\'file1.png\')', {
                    body: file,
                    json: false,
                    headers: {
                        'X-RequestDigest': digest,
                        'X-HTTP-Method': 'POST',
                        'IF-MATCH': '*',
                    }
                })
```